# Move rope swing along with player

Tags: java, physics

I'm making a game engine, and I want to have a rope object in the game. I've created the rope, and it behaves perfectly, except that if I apply a force to the bottom of the rope (like attaching the player to the rope and moving the player), the force doesn't propagate to the rest of the rope.

This is what the rope looks like, even when I try to move the player:
[image: straight rope]

I would like the rope to move along with the player, but keep the player attached to the bottom of the rope.

This is the update method from the Rope class

```
public void update() {

    for (int i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++) {
        RopeSegment previous = null;

        if (i != 0) {
            previous = segments.get(i - 1);
        }
        final RopeSegment seg = segments.get(i);

        // do collision detection
        seg.update();
        // if we are not the first (position locked) segment
        if (previous != null) {
            // if we are out of range of the previous segment
            if (seg.getCenter().toPoint().distanceSq(previous.getCenter().toPoint()) > MAX_DIST * MAX_DIST) {
                // pull us back in
                final Vec2D previousCenter = previous.getPosition();
                seg.applyForce(previousCenter.subtract(seg.getPosition()).multiply(0.01));
                seg.setPosition(previousCenter.add(seg.getPosition().subtract(previousCenter).unit()
                        .multiply(MAX_DIST)));
            }
        }
    }
    // lock position of first segment
    segments.get(0).setPosition(getLockposition());
    segments.get(0).setVelocity(new Vec2D(0, 0));
}
```

and this is the relevant code from the update method of the Player class

```
if (rope != null) {
    if (rope.getLockposition().toPoint().distanceSq(getCenter().toPoint()) > Rope.MAX_DIST * Rope.MAX_DIST) {
        setCenter(rope.getLastSegment().getCenter());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear (for me) : Should the rope be stretched? Or should it start to swing? (I guess the latter, due to the image)

Comment: Yeah, it should start to swing, but it just stays still.

Comment: At which point in the posted code is the player movement considered? This solely seems to modify the rope. Is the player applying a force to one rope segment, by calling `applyForce` to the last segment, maybe from another method? Are the forces in the rope *accumulated* (and not *reset* each time that `applyForce` is called)?

Comment: Applyforce basically adds the parameter vector to the objects velocity. It's not reset every time it is called.

Comment: It really sounds like an interesting question, but in the current form, it's hard to find an "answer". A http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is probably out of scope, so one could only *guess* what some of the methods do, how (in which sequence) they are called, and how to modify the behavior accordingly. The `update` method looks like the position information is *only* propagated from the *start* of the rope to the *end*, and not from the end (where the player is) to the start, but maybe I overlooked something here.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you: I would find the number of rope segments (Depending on height), there are between the player and the top of the screen (Y : 0px); thereby, allowing you to constantly update an integer; or appropriate size variable, with how many segments to draw. Then, every time you redraw, you can make the rope above the player. This would entitle deleting most of what you have, but I believe it to be a bit more efficient.
 If you want to make the rope look more 'Rope Like', then you could use an `ArrayList`, updated every time you go to draw, which will have a class defining position and a `Vec2D` which holds velocity, which will be used to increase the x position of the rope. e.g.

```
List<Rope> ropes = new ArrayList<>(); //Fill This With Ropes. . . //First is The Farthest Up!

class Rope {
    int x, y;
    short velocity;
    //Constructor
} 

void updateRopes(int playerX) {
    for(Rope r : ropes)
       r.x += (r.velocity < (playerX - r.x)) ? r.velocity : (playerX - r.x); //You Can Make a Variable Which Holds (playerX - r.x) For Efficiency, or Keep For RAM
}

void playerMove() {
     int yDec = ropes.size() / 5; //5 Is the Presumable Speed of The Character. . . 
     int tempVeloc = 5;
     for(int i = 0; i < ropes.size(); i++)
        if((i % yDec) == 0 & i != 0) tempVeloc -= 1;
     //The Other Player-Move Based Code. . .
}
```

`EDIT:`
I believe your problem is that you are not actually editing the classes inside of the array, you are making a constant copy of them; thereby not changing the object because you have not made a pointer to them. . .
What you should do is this:

```
RopeSegment seg = segments.get(i - 1);
```

Comment: I actually do have an arraylist of segments, the only problem right now is that they move the player, the player just can't pull on the rope.

Comment: So, does the player stay suspended in air, or does the rope not move horizontally?

Comment: Both. The player stays attached to the rope like he should, but when force is applied to the player (he tries to move) the rope does not move and neither does the player.

Comment: I think; since I do not have all your code, that you are going into an infinite loop: when you tried to recur back to update the other segments. . . Also you're not editing the classes from the List, your are just making a final version of them; that is, not a reference, resulting in the rope not being edited!

Comment: Also, I like the lighting in your engine; did you use a library, or make your own?

Comment: I actually did my own. Basically, you draw radial gradients onto an image, then invert the alpha channel. I also used a glow filter optimized from this guy: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/index.html

Comment: That's what I thought :). Did I answer your question?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: You do not seem to be editing the first segment, which could lead to no force being applied to the other segments (It's hard to tell because of the lack of explanation of: the uses of your methods). If this is so, I would apply a minimal amount of force to the first segment. Secondly, much of your code is very 'unreadable', thus making it very hard to debug, if I were you I would go with the concept I have provided, it raises efficiency and increases readability. Also what does distanceSq() do, this is quite important because of its crucial role in enabling the application of force. . .